# codeigniter view $class not working correct

Tags: php, codeigniter

On my codeigniter project with HMVC on my view page the $class is not showing correct one. When I try to view my modules if there is no column left or right it should go to **col-sm-12**

For some reason it shows **col-sm-9** when it should be **col-sm-12** if no column left or right.

```
<?php echo $header; ?>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row"><?php echo $column_left; ?>
    <?php if ($column_left && $column_right) { ?>
    <?php $class = 'col-sm-6'; ?>
    <?php } elseif ($column_left || $column_right) { ?>
    <?php $class = 'col-sm-9'; ?>
    <?php } else { ?>
    <?php $class = 'col-sm-12'; ?>
    <?php } ?>
    <div id="content" class="<?php echo $class; ?>"><?php echo $content_top; ?><?php echo $content_bottom; ?></div>
    <?php echo $column_right; ?></div>
</div>
<?php echo $footer; ?>
```

How can I make it display col-sm-12 if no column-left or column-right?

Thanks in advance.

**Added Controller**

```
<?php defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Home extends MX_Controller {

public function index() {
    $data['column_left'] = Modules::run('catalog/common/column_left/index');
    $data['column_right'] = Modules::run('catalog/common/column_right/index');
    $data['content_top'] = Modules::run('catalog/common/content_top/index');
    $data['content_bottom'] = Modules::run('catalog/common/content_bottom/index');
    $data['footer'] = Modules::run('catalog/common/footer/index');
    $data['header'] = Modules::run('catalog/common/header/index');

    return $this->load->view('theme/default/template/common/home_view', $data);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to put those thousand php opening and closing tags.

```
<?php 
    if (!empty($column_left) && !empty($column_right)) {
        $class = 'col-sm-6'; 
    } elseif (!empty($column_left) || !empty($column_right)) {
        $class = 'col-sm-9';
    } else { 
        $class = 'col-sm-12';
    } 
?>
```

**UPDATED**

Remove return from this statement

```
return $this->load->view('theme/default/template/common/home_view', $data);
```

This should be :

```
$this->load->view('theme/default/template/common/home_view', $data);
```

Comment: Still shows out put `class="col-sm-9" ` `class="<?php echo $class;?>"`

Comment: return $this->load->view('theme/default/template/common/home_view', $data);  Remove return from this statement.

Comment: I did that and also for got to add id as shown in my answer as well all works now.

Comment: Great to know it helped.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76989/discussion-between-wolfgang1983-and-tiger).

Answer (score 1):

```
elseif(empty($column_left) || empty($column_right)){ ?>
    <?php $class = 'col-sm-12'; ?>
    <?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

If `$column_left` or `$column_right` is set then it will never reach the last `else` part. Just check with `!empty()`. It will check if the value is empty or not.

```
<?php if ($column_left && $column_right) { ?>
<?php $class = 'col-sm-6'; ?>
<?php } elseif (!empty($column_left) || !empty($column_right)) { ?>
<?php $class = 'col-sm-9'; ?>
<?php } else { ?>
<?php $class = 'col-sm-12'; ?>
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I found out what problem was it was most simplest thing I had forgotten the to add the id on my column left and right

And thanks to @tiGer of the remove return also helped

Column Left Module

```
<?php if ($modules) { ?>
<column id="column-left" class="col-sm-3 hidden-xs">
  <?php foreach ($modules as $module) { ?>
  <?php echo $module; ?>
  <?php } ?>
</column>
<?php } ?>
```

Column Right

```
<?php if ($modules) { ?>
<column id="column-right" class="col-sm-3 hidden-xs">
  <?php foreach ($modules as $module) { ?>
  <?php echo $module; ?>
  <?php } ?>
</column>
<?php } ?>
```